# Creation of CustomToken errored: VM error: revert

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts

I new to solidity so could you guys please help me thanks? I tried to deploy the contract will ETH Value but always got the error "The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.".
Is there any way to fix this?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract CustomToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol){
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10 ** 18);
    }
}

contract Uniswap {
    // Custom tokens to be initialiazed
    string[] public tokens = ["CoinA", "CoinB", "CoinC"];

    // map to maintain the tokens and its instances
    mapping(string => ERC20) public tokenInstanceMap;

    // 1 CoinA/CoinB/COinC = 0.0001 eth
    uint256 ethValue = 100000000000000;

    // 0.0001 eth = 1 CoinA/CoinB/CoinC
    // 1 CoinA/CoinB/CoinC = 1 CoinA/CoinB/CoinC

    constructor() {
        for (uint i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
            CustomToken token = new CustomToken(tokens[i], tokens[i]);
            tokenInstanceMap[tokens[i]] = token;
        }
    }

    function getBalance(string memory tokenName, address _address) public view returns (uint256) {
        return tokenInstanceMap[tokenName].balanceOf(_address);
    }

    function getTotalSupply(string memory tokenName) public view returns (uint256) {
        return tokenInstanceMap[tokenName].totalSupply();
    }

    function getName(string memory tokenName) public view returns (string memory) {
        return tokenInstanceMap[tokenName].name();
    }

    function getTokenAddress(string memory tokenName) public view returns (address) {
        return address(tokenInstanceMap[tokenName]);
    }

    function getEthBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function swapEthToToken(string memory tokenName) public payable returns (uint256) {
        uint256 inputValue = msg.value;
        uint256 outputValue = (inputValue / ethValue) * 10 ** 18; // Convert to 18 decimal places
        require(tokenInstanceMap[tokenName].transfer(msg.sender, outputValue));
        return outputValue;
    }

    

    
}
```

I try with 0 ETH and it worked fine!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtLNt.png)
However, with 1 ETH and it got error message
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsjE0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function needs to use the `payable` modifier in order to accept ETH.

When you're deploying a contract, it executes the `constructor`.

```
constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) ERC20(name, symbol) payable {
    _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10 ** 18);
}
```

Comment: Why would a constructor require to be payable? e.g where is the payment used

Comment: @johnny5 In this case, the ETH payment stays on the contract address.... For example a common use case of payable constructor is initialization of a timelock contract. Instead of sending 2 transactions (one deployment, one deposit), you can deposit along with the deployment.